# ember.js load data in dialog

Tags: ember.js

i try to create my first ember.js app. A calendar-

my day model

```
App.Day = Ember.Object.extend({
today : null,
dayNumber : null,
addEvent : function()   {
    console.log(this);
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
}
});
```

the html view

```
<div class="cal">
    {{#each App.DayList}}
        {{#if this.today}}
        <div class="day today" {{action "addEvent" target="model" }}>
            {{#with this as model}}
            <span class="text">{{this.dayNumber}}</span>
            {{/with}}
        </div>
        {{else}}
        <div class="day" {{action "addEvent" target="model" }}>
            {{#with this as model}}
            <span class="text">{{this.dayNumber}}</span>
            {{/with}}
        </div>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
    </div>
```

so on click on day i show the bootstrap dialog and I wont to load extern data, but I need a information about clicked day.

My understanding is I create a view

```
  App.DayDetails = Ember.View.extend({

});
```

and inside this view I send an ajax request, but how to get information about clicked day inside this view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should almost *never* be doing any AJAX in a view.

Views do two things:

(1) draw themselves

(2) respond to UI events (clicks, typing, etc)

Your view should get its contents from a controller, in this case I suppose App.DayController or DayDetailsController. (that's another thing, it's best practice to end your subclasses with `View` or `Controller`, etc, so its obvious at a glance what they do).

Where the controller gets that data from is where things might get complicated. Ideally, in a mature app, you'd have a data store (a combination—in concept—of your server-side database and ActiveRecord, if you use rails) that would be queried. Simplistically, however, you could have the controller be responsible for using jQuery to manually handle an ajax request. So long as we're taking short-cuts, you could put such a call in a number of place, (a singleton controller, a day-specific item controller, the day model itself), just NOT the view. And it's important when taking these sorts of short-cuts to limit the contagion... all you should be doing with the manual ajax is fetching the JSON and then immediately and expeditiously getting it back into the ember ecosystem by setting it as the content of an array controller. I.e., no going one or two steps further by trying to insert the data into a view manually or whatnot. Don't fight Ember, if you can avoid it.

A few things:

(1) Your use of `this` is superfluous, as are the `{{with}}` statements. Inside an `{{each}}` block the context will be the current object (or its wrapping controller, if you're using itemController) in the iteration. (UNLESS you use "x in y" syntax, in which case the context remains the controller)

(2) The model should NOT be attempting to modify the DOM. Instead, rely on bindings and your controllers to coordinate UI changes. What you might want to do is have a `App.DayController` that you can put `addEvent` on, and then in your `{{each}}` use `itemController="App.DayController".`

```
App.DayController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    addEvent: function () {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Then, the context for each loop in your `{{each}}` template will be each individual day controller. The controller will automatically be the target and context for the views so your template would look like this:

```
{{#each App.DayList itemController="App.DayController"}}
    <div {{bindAttr class=":day today"}} {{action addEvent}}>{{dayNumber}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

(the `:` in `:day` means that `day` will always be a class, but `today` will only be a class if the `today` property on the context is truthy)

Because each day sends `addEvent` to its own controller, there's no need for figuring out what day to load.

Comment: Alternatively you could eschew the DayController/itemController scheme and pass the current item (as `this`) to an addEvent action on the DayList as an argument.